# How can I combine two arrays of arrays in a particular way in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, delegates, combinations

Lets say that I have these two arrays of arrays:

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = [[4],[5],[6]]
```

is there an option that allows me to combine them like this:

```
a.combined_somehow(b) == [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

as I want it to prevent me from duplicates in the inner arrays.I mean, if it was:

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = [[1],[5],[3]]
```

the output would be then: `[[1],[2,5],[3]]`

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = [[4],[5],[6]]

a.flatten.zip(b.flatten).map(&:uniq) # => [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]] 

b = [[1],[5],[3]]
a.flatten.zip(b.flatten).map(&:uniq) # => [[1], [2, 5], [3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'pp'

a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = [[1],[5],[3]]

def combine( a, b )
  [ a.flatten, b.flatten ].transpose.map(&:uniq)
end

pp combine( a, b )
```

outputs

```
[[1], [2, 5], [3]]
```

Comment: No need of require.a.flatten.zip(b.flatten).uniq! works perfectly fine .

Comment: Right; the pp (pretty print) is just to print the output. Using ".uniq!" doesn't seem to work for me.. Putting `.uniq` at the end would eliminate duplicate matrices, but not inner elements as you requested.

Comment: Lets say that this is iteration over each and every inner array.So it removes the duplicates from the inner arrays.

Comment: @user2128702 Let's not say that, because that is not what is happening.  Matt is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just feels a bit more Rubyish in my opinion:

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = [[4],[5],[6]]

p a.zip(b).map(&:flatten) #=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]

a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = [[1],[5],[3]]

p a.zip(b).map{|x|x.flatten.uniq} #=> [[1], [2, 5], [3]]
```

Comment: 6 versus 0.5 dozen; the others too.

Comment: Sure, but in Ruby there are always many ways to do something. I feel this way is slightly more interesting than the other answers as: 1, it follows the DRY principle (flatten used once), and it is extendable to  any number of arrays.

Comment: True, though being able to use `to_proc` is nice.  On balance, however, I'm inclined to agree with you, and your point that it can be extended to multiple arrays (by adding a single character!) is icing on the cake.

Answer (score 0):

I would go as below :

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = [[4],[5],[6]]
a.map.with_index{|e,i| e | b[i]}
# => [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]

a = [[1],[2],[3]]
b = [[4],[2],[6]]
a.map.with_index{|e,i| e | b[i]}
# => [[1, 4], [2], [3, 6]]
```